# Auto increment primary key in JOIN Tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, join, increment

I have an existing table `Books` like this:

```
Book ISBN | Ranking | Price | Lent(true/false)
```

Now I want to create a new table from `Books` but with full range of Ranking from 1 to 20, sorted on Ranking.

So the new Table will look like this:

```
Ranking | Book ISBN | Price | Lent
```

I hope this makes sense since I try to abstract what I'm doing for a project. I think this is kind like join two tables together with a condition set on Ranking. Some sample data:

Books:

```
12345222 | 1 | $10 | FALSE
98001333 | 3 | $15 | TRUE
78899444 | 4 | $20 | FALSE
```

New Table:

```
1 | 12345222 | $10 | FALSE
2 | 00000000 | $0  | FALSE
3 | 98001333 | $15 | TRUE
4 | 78899444 | $20 | FALSE
5 | 00000000 | $0  | FALSE
```

...

Is there any other better way to create this new table? Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "full range of Ranking from 1 to 20" Does the `Ranking` field in `Books` contains values 1 through 20, or are you wanting to filter only `books` that have a `ranking` with a value of 1 through 20? When you say you want a `New Table` do you mean you want a result set? I don't see any need for auto-increment here, nor are you joining two tables, so I'm not sure what your Title has to do with the question either. Perhaps if you post some sample table data and a sample of the result you are looking for things would be more clear.

Comment: Right now as you've explained your problem I understand that you want to change the column order of your table. Though, I'm almost certain this is not what you're trying to do. Please clarify.

Comment: You need to include sample data and expected results, and show us what you have already tried.

Comment: Sorry I'm new here. Please be gentle. Thanks all for the comments.

Comment: What version of SQL Server?  I get what you're trying to do.  You want to insert rows with default values for each missing rank (e.g, you don't have a book ranked 2)

Comment: @Stuart Ainsworth: SQL Server 2012. Yes, the new table has 20 rows and it will be auto-filled with defaults for the missing rows.

Comment: see my answer below, and welcome to stackoverflow.  you may want to wait and see if anyone else offers a better solution, but if not, please mark it as answered :)

Comment: @Stuart Ainsworth: Thanks. Maybe some people think I'm asking a stupid question and have given me 3 thumb-downs.:( I think your example would work for me. If no one else answers, I'll mark your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
;
WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT TOP 20
                        ranking = ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY c.name )
               FROM     sys.columns c
             )
    INSERT INTO newTable
    SELECT  cte.ranking
          , '00000000' AS ISBN
          , 0 AS price
          , 'FALSE' AS Lent
    FROM    cte
            LEFT JOIN Books b ON cte.ranking = b.ranking
    WHERE   b.ISBN IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  ranking
          , ISBN
          , price
          , Lent
    FROM    books;
```